# “a small number of” as an adjective

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adjectives, subjects

The official Australian government page https://www.nationalsecurity.gov.au/national-threat-level/current-national-terrorism-threat-level features the following quote.

> This is because there **are** a small number of people in Australia and overseas who want to cause Australia harm.

If instead of “a small number of” the page used an adjective like “few” I would see the sentence as correct. It strikes me as odd, though, how with the sentence as it is,”are” is used instead of “is” as I see “number” as the subject of the sentence.

Is the sentence correct in its current form? If so, what special construct is “a small number of” and why can it be used as an adjective instead of being the subject of the sentence?

Comment: Note that if we use *few* as suggested, and not *a few*, the meaning reverses. I'd say 'good' if few people wanted to hurt us.

Comment: Yes. Phrases like this are called _Quantifiers_. They are a type of _Determiner_. Determiners are not adjectives and have their own grammatical peculiarities; for one thing, they precede adjectives in a noun phrase.. And they tend to screw up number agreement on verbs, because the noun in the determiner phrase is often singular while the head noun is plural, or the other way around. Don't worry about number agreement; it adds no information and nobody cares except English teachers.

Comment: @YosefBaskin definitely. I wasn‘t looking for a direct synonym, just an adjective that made grammatical sense. @fev‘s “several” fits best

Comment: @JohnLawler that makes sense. So would “is” be fine as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of plural is inherent to the phrase ***a number of***. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20number%20of) defines it as meaning

> more than two but fewer than many : several
>
> - There ***are*** *a number of* different options to choose from.

However, [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=number) pinpoints the cause of confusion:

> As a collective noun ***number*** *may take either a singular or a plural
> verb*.
>  It takes a **singular** verb when it is *preceded by the definite
> article* ***the***:
>
> - ***The** number of* skilled workers ***is*** increasing.
>
> It takes a
> **plural** verb *when preceded by the indefinite article **a***:
>
> - ***A** number of* the
>   workers ***have*** learned new skills.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/explore/number-of-people-is-or-are) goes a bit further explaining that

> Although the expression *‘a number’* is *strictly singular*, the phrase ***‘a number of’*** *is used with plural nouns* (as what grammarians call a [determiner](https://www.lexico.com/definition/determiner)). The verb should therefore be plural:
>
> ***A number of*** people ***are*** waiting for the bus.

So in your sentence, the head of the Subject NP is ***people***, not *number*. Read it as:

> there are ***SEVERAL*** <sub>*[a small number of]*</sub> people in Australia and overseas...